# IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5, concurrency

I am looking to install Windows 7 Ultimate and run IIS 7.5 on it.  However, I would like to know exactly what my limitations will be with this setup.  While researching this topic various resources have stated that I am limited to 20 device connections (Microsoft Software License Terms), whereas I read other limitations from other sources.

http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm

It says that there is a "simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows multiple sites".  Does this mean that I can only serve 10 concurrent connections.  How many web sessions can I serve?

Thank-you in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: IIS on client versions of Windows has only ever been intended for development purposes, and you are unlikely to ever legitimately encounter the connection limit if you are only using it as intended. If you're planning on using Windows 7 as a server for a production website, it is a *Very Bad Idea™* for more reasons that I care to list.

Comment: If you run into the limit you're probably using it for the wrong purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The limit means that IIS will queue all incoming requests, and will process the queue as fast as 10 at a time. You should not encounter errors unless the queue fills up (the limit is in the thousands) before IIS can work through it. [[Source](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/05/01/understanding-iis7-request-restrictions-on-windows-vista.aspx), [Source](http://forums.iis.net/t/1055753.aspx)]